# updating csv file automatically in listview c++/cli

Tags: listview, csv, c++-cli

I have created a listview in VS2010 c++/cli and then all items are saving in a *.csv file.
I have done more in listview by right clicking on item which will delete item from listview.

```
private: System::Void removeFromListToolStripMenuItem_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    listView1->Items->Remove(listView1->SelectedItems[0]);
}
```

[image]
It can be deleted from listview but I could not figure out how could save the modified listview.
Does anyone an idea ho one could do it?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to iterate through the items in your listview every time you remove or add one. I recommend writing a function for that, so that you can call it more often without always writing the code again:

```
void WriteItemsToCsv(){
    StreamWriter^ CsvWriter = gcnew StreamWriter(/* Path to your .csv file */);
    for each(ListViewItem^ li in listView1->Items)
        CsvWriter->WriteLine(li->Text + ",");

    CsvWriter->Close();
}
```

This way, every time you call `WriteItemsToCsv()` it will write all the names of your `listView1` into the specified File. Remember to insert the path to the file at CsvWriter's declaration.

**EDIT**
My fault, separation in .csv are no ; but , . Edited in the codesample.

**EDIT 2 DataGridView Solution**

1. Add a DataGridView onto your form in your designer.
2. Add a DataSet onto your form in your designer.
3. In your DataGridView's properties at "DataSource" choose your DataSet.
4. In your DataSet you now create the table which will represent your persons.
5. Click your DataSet and click the browser symbol next to property "Tables".
6. There you add your Table with all necessary properties. It should then look like this:

[image]

In your code, now you can use `DataSet->ReadXml("test.xml");` to read and afterwards you write the data to the xml like `DataSet->WriteXml("test.xml");`.

Tell me if this works out for you ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It works fine just only for the first column of the list view. Can you please let me know how I could expand it for `subitems`, as well

Comment: @Royeh Well thats a little harder now because you need an identifier if its a subitem or a root. In the .csv you would only have the names of the items saved.

Comment: Right, my problem is that I have a ``listview`` of 7 columns and then I need to update all of columns not only the first column.

Comment: @Royeh I don't see what you are trying to do. What kind of listview are you using? You could edit you question and provide a picture maybe.

Comment: I added a picture of my ``listview`` window

Comment: @Royeh Ok. Since you not only have a List but got some kind of data `person` I'd recommend you to maybe use DataGridView. Its members include some nice functionalities like saving and reading from a .xml file.

Comment: Thanks, because I am not familiar with DataGridView an I am out of time, then I have to find out some way to use what you suggest. Do you think that I could be able to use another for loop inside the for loop above and then solve my problem? something like this:

`for each(ListViewItem^ li in listView1->Items->Item[j]->SubItems)`

which `j` is the number of rows of the `*.cvs` file (I have written a function to find it).

Comment: @Royeh I added the DataGridView Solution.